# Script is creating files for unknown reason

Tags: bash, file, wc

I wrote a script which should check if files were written in specific folders. For unknown reason, this script also creates a file in each of these folder with the name "0". Does anyone have an idea, why this is happening?

```
sFolders=$(ls -d /opt/sftp/pharmatest/*/*/uploaded/)
declare -a sUploaded=()
declare -a dirs=($sFolders)

for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        declare -i iDatei=$(ls $i | wc -l)
        if [ $iDatei > 0 ]
        then
                sUploaded=(${sUploaded[@]} $i)
        fi
done;

printf '%s\n' "${sUploaded[@]}" >> /opt/sftp/pharmatest/logfile.log
```

My guess is, that "declare -i iDatei=$(ls $i | wc -l)" is creating them, because even if I remove all files in the directories, which should be checked by the script, the output to the logfile always contains every folder that was checked and therefore the if statement was always fullfilled.

Thanks in advance,

Ingo

Answer (score 1):

`if [ $iDatei > 0 ]` is not a valid use for `test`, you should write `if [ $iDatei -gt 0 ]`

What you are doing here is `$iDatei > 0`, this is called a redirection and will create a file named `0` with the output of `$iDatei`

Comment: `>` does not use a pipe, it is called *redirection*. It will not write the contents of `$iDatei`.  An alternative is : `if (( iDatei > 0 ))`

Comment: Thanks for the answers!